# How to rollback to a specific migration successfully in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to Code-first migration world and i need some help to understand how to rollback without problems.

I made the following *EF migrations* :

```
201512050853073_InitialCreate
201512050919315_AutomaticMigration
201512050922156_AutomaticMigration
201512051442428_add_SourceProperty
201512051447812_add_TargetProperty
```

The last Migration : i add property[`Target`] to my class and add that migration.then update my database successfully .

---

Now if i want to rollback the last migration :
Should i just Run `update-database -TargetMigration "add_SourceProperty" -verbose` ?

or run the previous command then delete the `[Target]` property and delete also the

```
`201512051447812_add_TargetProperty.cs` file ?
```

Comment: Whether you delete it or not depends on whether you might want to utilize it again.

Comment: Yes you would run the command that you specified above.  I probably wouldn't delete your migration file.  It doesn't hurt anything to have it there and as long as it is properly named it won't get confused with anything else.

Comment: I have rolled back and deleted many times in my DEV environment. Another approach if it involves non DEV environments is to remove the Target property from the class and generate a new migration (remove_TargetProperty). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680446/entity-framework-rollback-and-remove-bad-migration

Comment: When i run just the command and run the application i find the last rollback lose its effect,and when i remove the property i get `Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. ` ,i'm so confused